# How to capture the visible page screenshot in one step in Safari or another browser?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, screen-capture, firefox, safari-extensions

I have a large series of web pages to capture for documentation. Unfortunately it is mostly an interactive process, but can be repeated rather quickly.

At the moment I am using the dreaded "**Awesome Screenshot**" extension because it has had the shortest path to the desired result so far, but yet it still has an extra step that I would like to eliminate.

Presently when I click the "**Awesome Screenshot**" button in my toolbar I get an annotation page with the screenshot (*this is the step I'd like to eliminate*) and then upon clicking Done, I then get a draggable image.

Essentially I want to be able to initiate a shortcut (either by keypress or button click) and then immediately have an image to paste or drag into a document (e.g., in my case I want to paste it into PDFPen Pro to add it to the sequence).

Is there a way to shortcut this process in Safari, or any other browser on macOS for that matter, that will allow me to capture the visible portion of a webpage immediately to the pasteboard or to a draggable image so that capturing becomes a 1 step process?

Answer (score 1):

*So after a bit of playing with various options, I've come up with a pretty efficient solution:*

I've found that even though it's older, using [`Paparazzi`](https://derailer.org/paparazzi/) is the most efficient solution.  I was able to set some sane defaults for the file naming (using YYYY-MM-DD as a base) and the output resolution (around 1020 (width) x1320 (height) for ~120ppi (kept font size output for my monitor resolution at about the same size) letter (8.5"x11") gives me a nice ordered image output that I can then import into PDFPen or Preview, etc. to generate a nice sequential PDF from the output.

This leads to a simple navigation from page to page and a quick `cmd-s + <ENTER>` to save the image rapidly.